# Clojure NullPointerException with loop and recur

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception

I am new to Clojure and I am currently stuck with below code which throws a NullPointerException when I run it like this:

`(mapset inc [1 1 2 2])`

```
(defn mapset
    [fn v]
    (loop [[head & tail] v result-set (hash-set)]
      (if (nil? head)
        result-set)
      (conj result-set (fn head))
      (recur tail result-set)))
```

When I print the result-set in the if block it prints an empty set whereas I expect a set like this: #{2 3}

After trying to interpret the stacktrace I guess that the NullPointerException has something to do with the following line:
`(conj result-set (fn head))`.
The stacktrace and the fact that the resulting set is empty leads me to believe that the inc operation somehow gets called with nil as input.

I am glad about any explanation of why this error happens

The mentioned (shortend) stacktrace looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

Numbers.java: 1013  clojure.lang.Numbers/ops
Numbers.java:  112  clojure.lang.Numbers/inc
core.clj:  908  clojure.core/inc
core.clj:  903  clojure.core/inc
REPL:    6  user/mapset
REPL:    1  user/mapset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some small changes:

```
(defn mapset [f v]
  (loop [[head & tail] v
         result-set (hash-set)]
    (if (nil? head)
      result-set
      (let [res (f head)]
        (recur tail (conj result-set res))))))

(defn x-1 []
  (mapset inc [1 1 2 2]))

(x-1)
;;=> #{3 2}
```

So now `mapset` will call the function `f` on each of your inputs from `v`, then put the result of that call into the `hash-set` that was created at the outset.

The problem was in the control flow logic of your `if` statement. The flow of execution was continuing on after the `if`. Thus the function `fn` (which I renamed to `f`, rather than leave it as the name of a macro) was being called even when `head` was `nil`, which was not what you intended.

As originally coded the `if` (which would more clearly have been a `when`) was doing nothing useful. But once I realised you meant to have an `if`, but closed the paren off too early, then the answer slotted into place. Hence minor changes fixed the problem - your underlying logic was sound - and the amended function just worked.

Comment: Thank you very much. How could I not get that... You also have reminded me to use let for better clarity

Comment: np. I used the `let` to help with debugging - to have less going on on the one line. You could certainly get rid of it and I probably would - as `res` is only used once and is a silly name.